# solution to convert PDFs, DOCs, DOCXs into a textual format with python

Tags: python

I am developing a full text search engine for indexing popular binary formats. I know that there are hundereds of such questions (and solutions) already, but I found it tough to find one:

- cross platform
- supports DOC, DOCX and PDF formats at once
- easy to use with python
- can be set up in a major shared host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For PDFs, I recommend [PDFminer](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/).
- Try the [docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) module (I have not used it myself)
- I am not aware of any pure python module that can read `.doc` files.
- There are command-line tools to extract text from `.doc` files: antiword and catdoc (and probably others). If the packages are installed on your shared host, you could use `subprocess` to shell out to these tools. Available on Windows via Cygwin.
- [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) is a Java library that can extract text from Office documents. If your shared host has Java installed, you could write a bit of Java (or Jython) code and execute using `subprocess`.

Comment: According to an edit suggestion, the author used the docx module.

Answer (score 0):

If at server side you can use OpenOffice then you can use [unoconv: Convert between any document format supported by OpenOffice](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/unoconv/)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use google documents to extract the text contents from binary .doc-files. You upload the document to google docs and then download the text contents. It is a fairly slow process, but it is the only "pure Python" solution I know of since it doesn't require any external tools except for network access. An external tool such as catdoc or antiword is a much better solution if you are allowed to install it on your host.

Answer (score 0):

Textract uses the default tools for every kind of file.

https://github.com/deanmalmgren/textract