# python converter libraries for DOC, DOCX and PDF

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [solution to convert PDFs, DOCs, DOCXs into a textual format with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854665/solution-to-convert-pdfs-docs-docxs-into-a-textual-format-with-python)

I am making a document search engine which indexes popular binary formats. I am looking for python libraries for this purpose.

Reliable converters proved too hard to find. PyPDF never works accurately. Please reccomend:

- python libraries that convert these formats to text
- or cross-platform, standalone programs that can be called as a subprocess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can sort of read `.docx` by unzipping it and then rootling around in the resulting folder structure. See [How can I search a word in a Word 2007 .docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116139/how-can-i-read-a-word-2007-docx-file).
- If pyPDF isn't working for you, you can use [pdftotext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdftotext) as a subprocess.
- `.doc` is probably the hardest. Is COM scripting an option for you? That is, asking Word to open the file and export it as text? There's a linux utility [extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

You might try Open Office.

It's converting skills are above average.  For editing PDF documents, you need to install the [pdf import extension](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport).

There are some extensions to work with python, such as the [python-uno bridge](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python), but I've had difficulty with it, and generally resort to calling open office as a subprocess.

Just noticed you opened a duplicate question at:
[solution to convert PDFs, DOCs, DOCXs into a textual format with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854665/solution-to-convert-pdfs-docs-docxs-into-a-textual-format-with-python)...